# Design is not working with spans and button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align `button`s along side 2 `span`s. The 2 `span`s are on top of each other, and I want to display the `button` beside the second `span`.

Here's my CSS:

```css
/* Styles go here */

.contacts {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px;
}

.contacts .name {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">short name</span>
          <span class="city">City</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">very long name will be here</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">another long name will be here too</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>    
</html>
```

How do I align the `button`s to be under each other and not to move when the name is too long, can it be done without bootstrap?

Thanks for any hint about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove your `pull-right` class from your buttons.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.contacts {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px;
}

.contacts .name {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">short name</span>
          <span class="city">City</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">very long name will be here</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">another long name will be here too</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But how can I make it have a fixed distance from the left. when the city name length changes from one city to another, I want to buttons to stay aligned under each other, that's why I used pull-right. How can I do it?

Comment: @Karla So for example if a city has a long name, the rest of buttons should have a space between the span and the button?.

Comment: no, they should have fixed location. I don't know how to handle this case, maybe if a long city name it should have smaller font? I am not sure how to go around this.

Comment: @Karla Then I do not think you can do it only with CSS. Maybe you will need some Javascript. This is because you cannot handle when a city is very long or short with pure CSS. You can set a fixed width to the div that contains each `li` and set the button on the right of that div. But you will have to calculate more or less that any city will have a width more than the div.

Comment: @Yass Beware when you edit. You have changed the behaviour of my answer.

Comment: Apologies. I'll be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the updates below, and possibly clarify what you're looking for. The main issue is that the .contacts div doesn't have a width set, so it's defaulting to the contents included in its container. Expand it to fill 100% width (or whatever width you want really) and the buttons will always be on the right hand side, regardless of city length.

If that's not what you're looking for, please provide a more clear explanation or mockup.

```css
/* Styles go here */

.contacts {
    width: 100%;
}

.contacts .name {
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
}

ul {
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">short name</span>
          <span class="city">City</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">very long name will be here</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="contacts">
          <span class="name">another long name will be here too</span>
          <span class="city">city</span>
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">Contact</button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what I wanted actually, if there was only a way to mark 2 posts as an answer. +1